# rails console showing query at view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my view, i'm showing all the posts but its showing the text like when you go to the rails console and write

> r = Post.all

exactly all this thing and also the post information(title, content).

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Post id: 1, title: "321123123", content: "231123123123", created_at: "2015-11-14 00:44:31", updated_at: "2015-11-14 00:44:31">]>
```

So, this is on my view

```
<%= @alltheposts.each do |post| %>
    <div class="post_wrapper">
        <h2><a href=""><%= link_to post.title, post %></a></h2>
        <p><%= post.created_at.strftime("%A, %b %d") %></p>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

method index on my controller

```
    def index
       @alltheposts = Post.all.order("created_at desc")
    end
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey you have to replace

```
<%= @alltheposts.each do |post| %>
```

by this

```
<% @alltheposts.each do |post| %>
```

no need foor the = sign on each method

Comment: Thank you, i'm starting with it so i'm making some dumb mistakes. :)

Comment: you re pretty welcome, everything has a start, keep it up